# Swift: make UIScrollView have a "going out of focus" effect

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'd like to know which library/object/function I should refer to to be able to make my scroll views have that nice out of focus effect. For example make the image coming on screen look smaller as it goes away and blur it at the same time.
My scroll view contains ImageViews that take up the entire bounds of the scroll view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Blur**

For `iOS 8+`, you can use `UIVisualEffectView` to achieve this effect. This is a native API that has been fine tuned for performance and great battery life, and it's easy to implement. Alternatively you can check out `GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter` as described [here](http://five.agency/how-to-create-an-interactive-blur-effect-in-ios8/).

**Scale**

Check out `transform` property of the `UIView`. Using  CGAffineTransformMakeScale you can change the scale. Read [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html) very informative blog post about transformations.